# elementary OS unable to boot

Tags: boot

I'm dual booting elementary os Loki with windows 10 (Acer Aspire R-13), the install seems to work fine and I got up and running but when I shut down and restart the computer it defaults back to windows unless...

If the USB i installed off of is in the computer grub comes up for that I can press  type "exit" in then select "Unknown Device:" which is the install of element os, once i'm in the OS i can remove the USB no problem but I can't figure out the boot without it.

---

Random other info that may help, maybe but figured more info is useful
-I'm running a SSD
-My partions are labeled weird instead of sdXY they are under /dev/mapper and apparently can be gotten to by /dev/dm-Y
-I've tried reinstalling the OS 
-I've tried fixing Grub to no avail
- current linux partitions are "/", "swap" and "/home"

Comment: I have the same problem, but after the install. It goes back to the installation screen for elem.

Comment: disable "secure boot" option in BIOS

Answer (score 0):

The default boot manager is the Windows 10 boot loader, which can be bypassed though bios. You can boot into biod by rapidly pressing `esc` while booting up your computer and then press `f9` to bring up all the boot mangers. Then, navigate to `ubuntu`, and then `Elementary OS Loki`. After that the Elementary OS should begin.

If you don't want to do this every time you want to boot into Elementary you can always install [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), assuming you have a EFI based system.